# When can I translate the English prepositions ‘for’ and ‘to’ with their German cognates ‘für’ and ‘zu’?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

I am new to German. I am confused with translating the English prepositions *for* and *to*, which seem to be cognates of German *für* and *zu*, respectively.

> - *Das ist **für** dich.* – This is **for** you.
> - *Ich lade sie **zu** einer Party ein.* – I’m inviting her **to** a party.

Which verbs afford this intuitive substitution and which don’t?

Comment: Welcome. Could you specify, what does it work *what*?

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite this question almost completely, guessing on what the OP may have been wanting to ask, although I’m not sure it isn’t still too broad or unclear.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to learn for each verb which preposition has which meaning, for any language. Just consider the differences in "make out" and "make up".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the preposition 'for' can be translated in a couple of different ways, depending on the context. *für* is the most common, but in certain cases it is not idiomatic.

> Ich lade Sie zu einer Party ein

In this case, *zu* corresponds to 'I invite you *to* a party.'